# django: show sitemap.xml

Tags: django, sitemap, django-urls

I have a `sitemap.xml` file. Its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
    ...
    </url>
    <url>
     ...
    </url>
    <url>
    ...
    </url>
</urlset>
```

When I display it at http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml: I get:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></urlset>
```

I don't see all the urls! Is it a bug?

Here is the `urls.py` file:

```
(r'^sitemap\.xml/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='sitemap.xml', content_type='text/xml'))
```

Comment: Have you seen: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/ ?

Comment: When I use the sitemap framework, I have the same result. I can access the file but I can't see the `url` tags when I display  http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml in a web browser :(

Comment: Here is what I get with the framework: http://test.media-rewards.com/sitemap.xml -> empty xml file :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Django sitemap framework doesn't work for me:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/
I can't see any url tag when I check the sitemap.xml file in a web browser.

However, I used a website to auto-generate it:
http://www.web-site-map.com/xml_sitemap.php

Now I can see the whole content of the sitemap.xml file :).